# How long for data highlighter mark up to appear in structured data tool?

Tags: google, google-search-console, microdata, markup

I used the data highlighter in webmaster tools over 3 weeks ago to mark up some local business data, but there is still no structured data being detected in webmaster tools.

Does any body have any experience on approx how long it takes for Google Webmaster Tools to start reporting Structured Data that has been marked up with their data highlighter?

I'm asking specifically about reporting on it in Web Master Tools Structured Data section, as opposed to actually appearing in the SERPs.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly with anything Google there is nothing that is given in approx. time frames. This is because Google allocates resources to your site based on its authority and how busy their bot is. But in experience structured data normally appears between 1-6 weeks after the first index - it can take a few crawls before Google decides to display it within Google Webmaster tools, its also worth noting that Webmaster Tools is not real time compared and is often lagged behind to what your seeing in it's index, so basically Google may be away of your Structured data yet its not updated in WMT.

Answer (score 2):

As bybe mentioned, it can take a few weeks before your structured data begins to appear, and there have been some bugs in the reporting system lately.

However, I should mention that if you use Google's Data Highlighter Tool to mark up your page, Google's testing tool will not pick it up.  That's because the Highlighter Tool does not actually add HTML markup to your page.  Additionally, only Google will be aware of your markups.  So the best way to implement structured data on your site is to add the markups directly to your page's code.  In this way, all search engines that use structured data can extract it, and Google's testing tool will then, of course, be able to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Data highlighter normally takes 2-6 weeks to appear. Some times If your web site has good reputation, it can happen in 10 days also. You have to check for the keywords you have identified in the data highlighter tool.
In my case for some 4 keywords My data highlighter started working in 13 days, but for some other keywords(long tail keywords) it may take some time. As the CTR will go on creasing with time, you find your data highlighter will work for long tail keywords too.